# Regex accepts numbers but it shouldn't

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
/\s*([A-ZÖÜÄ]{1}([a-zöüä]){2,15})(([-| von ]?[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1}[a-zöüä]{2,15})*?)/u
```

This should not accept any numbers, but it does, strangely it works for the first three characters (excluding spaces).

This: Pe2 is not accepted according to the code. That's o.k - 
 but: Pet2 is accepted, and I can't find out why. 
Actually I don't want any numbers to go through at all.

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: did you use `^` and `$` to limit matching to a full line? So: `/^\s*([A-ZÖÜÄ]{1}([a-zöüä]){2,15})(([-| von ]?[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1}[a-zöüä]{2,15})*?)$/u`

Comment: I've tried that before, but it didn't help. The closest I could get was with this.

Comment: It's matching 'Pet', but since you don't anchor to end of string (or better, beginning and ending of string) using ^ and $, it allows '2' to exist as not being part of the match. Minimally, adding a '`$`' to the end of the pattern causes Pet2 to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `^` and `$` anchor and I'm pretty sure that `[-| von ]?` doesn't match what you think it should, I guess you want `(?:-| von )?`

your regex should be:

```
/^\s*[A-ZÖÜÄ][a-zöüä]{2,15}(?:(?:-| von )?[A-ZÖÜÄ][a-zöüä]{2,15})*$/u
```

And I guess the delimiter isn't optional, so:

```
/^\s*[A-ZÖÜÄ][a-zöüä]{2,15}(?:(?:-| von )[A-ZÖÜÄ][a-zöüä]{2,15})*$/u
```

Comment: Good, but use `(?:-| von )` instead of `(?:-| von )?`.  It makes no sense for the delimiter to be optional inside the enclosing, optional group.

Comment: @AlanMoore: I agree with you, I've just taken from OP.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this one:

```
^\s*([A-ZÖÜÄ]{1}([a-zöüä]){2,15})(([-| von ]?[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1}[a-zöüä]{2,15})*?)$
```

Pt2 => not OK
Pet2 => not OK

You can try your regex directly online. There is also a debuger and some documention. Very useful: http://regex101.com/

Hope that's help ;)

Comment: The OP didn't make it explicit, but I'm pretty sure `Foo-Bar` and `Foo von Bar` both should match.  Your regex only matches `Foo-Bar`.